# How can you get a turret docking unit in starmade?

Tags: starmade

I am trying to make a turret to protect my new station, but the shop refuses to sell them, claiming they are too old for use. I cannot /give one in either. It is like they don't even exist anymore. Is there any way to get one? PS: I don't care if it involves cheats.

Answer (score 4):

The old turret docking blocks just exist to keep old creations from crashing the game.  It has been replaced with the new rail docking system.  You have to place the turret rail axis block in order to make turrets now.  Place the turret rail axis block at the point you want you turret to connect to the station, but make sure it is rotated correctly!  The arrows are where you connect to it, and the direction the turret considers "forward".

On your turret "ship" have a rail docking unit (watch the arrows like before.  They must point in the forward direction of the turret.)  Press T while in flight mode to bring up the control menu, then select the rail docking unit from the control menu.  Now simply use it on the turret axis rail like you are shooting a gun.  This should connect the turret to the base and allow it to pivot.  If you place a BOBBY AI core on it and set it to turretmode, it should work.

If you want your turret to aim up and down you have to place another turret on the side of the base turret.  In this case the Bobby ai module needs to be on the part that rotates up and down in order for it to work.

Comment: Welcome on Arqade ! This is a good answer. Please consider reading the [Tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) page, to continue in that way !